# Change pixel null reference exception when image is not stored in local folder

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to change the pixels of images to Red, the images are downloaded from server and are not stored in local folder. The below code I am using and it works perfectly fine when image is stored in local folder.

```
    private ImageSource changeimagepixel(string p)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(p, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        ImageSource imgsource = new BitmapImage(uri);
        image.Source = imgsource;

        WriteableBitmap image1 = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)image.Source);
        WriteableBitmap image2 = ChangeColor(image1);
        image.Source = image2;
        return image.Source;
    }

    public static WriteableBitmap ChangeColor(WriteableBitmap scrBitmap)
    {
        //You can change your new color here. Red,Green,LawnGreen any..
        Color newColor =Colors.Red;
        Color actulaColor;
        //make an empty bitmap the same size as scrBitmap
        WriteableBitmap newBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(scrBitmap.PixelWidth, scrBitmap.PixelHeight);
        for (int i = 0; i < scrBitmap.PixelWidth; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < scrBitmap.PixelHeight; j++)
            {
                //get the pixel from the scrBitmap image
                actulaColor = scrBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                // > 150 because.. Images edges can be of low pixel colr. if we set all pixel color to new then there will be no smoothness left.
                if (actulaColor.A > 150)
                    newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, (Color)newColor);
                else
                    newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, actulaColor);
            }
        }
        return newBitmap;
    }
```

Here, **p** is the **URL** of image obtained from server and I am getting **NullReference Exception** at

```
WriteableBitmap image1 = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)image.Source);
```

Please anyone suggest a solution,to change the pixel of image which are not in local folder and obtained from server.

It would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: is it caused by [BitmapImage.CreateOptions Property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9212517/815938)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for it to download completely before you do any operations to it.

Example:

```XAML
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
    <Image x:Name="myImage"></Image>
</Grid>
```

```C#
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // download my dogecoin image
        myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.chubosaurus.com/dogecoin_wp8.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));           

        // hook the download complete 
        myImage.ImageOpened += bi_ImageOpened;
    }

    // image has downloaded completely, do your actions afterwards
    void bi_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ..... your code
        // put a break point here, you will see it will break when the image has downloaded
    }
 }
```

---

If the event is not firing -- it is most likely because you created the `Image` dynamically without adding it to the Visual Tree, so to fix this do something like this

```XAML
<!-- the default ContentPanel when creating the project -->
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <!--- your content -->
</Grid>
```

```C#
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    Image mytestimage = new Image();
    mytestimage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    mytestimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.chubosaurus.com/dogecoin_wp8.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));           

    // add it to the Visual Tree as a child of ContentPanel
    this.ContentPanel.Children.Add(mytestimage);

    // hook the download complete
    mytestimage.ImageOpened += mytestimage_ImageOpened;            
}

// image has been downloaded successfully
void mytestimage_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Chubosaurus Software. I will try and update you.Should I add this after the below line?      ImageSource imgsource = new BitmapImage(uri);

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar let me edit the solution to fit your previous code.  But it definitely correctly, you must wait until it is downloaded.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar I updated the solution, create a new project and step through the code and you will realize what is going on.  Then make some changes to your program with your new found knowledge.

Comment: Is it possible to return image.Source from bi_ImageOpened event?

Comment: and my webservice is REST service and imageurl is appearing,but its not entering in ImageOpened method

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar if the event is not firing it is because it's not part of the VisualTree, add it to a container and set its visibility to Collapsed.  (See minor edit on the solution)