# How to change pixel colour of image coming from server in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to change image pixel colour of image which is stored at server. For that I have used a library named **WriteableBitmapEx** which I obtained from Nugget Package Manager. I am trying to do this using ImageConverter as follows:

```
public class ImagePixelConverter:IValueConverter
{
    BitmapImage image;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string imageUrl = value.ToString();

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                byte[] imagebytes=new byte[e.Result.Length];
                e.Result.Read(imagebytes,0,imagebytes.Length);
                image.SetSource(e.Result);
                WriteableBitmap image1 = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)image);
                WriteableBitmap image2 = ChangeColor(image1);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                image2.SaveJpeg(ms, image2.PixelWidth, image2.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                image.SetSource(ms);

            };
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(imageUrl,UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        return image;
    }

    public static WriteableBitmap ChangeColor(WriteableBitmap scrBitmap)
    {
        //You can change your new color here. Red,Green,LawnGreen any..
        Color newColor = Colors.Red;
        Color actulaColor;
        //make an empty bitmap the same size as scrBitmap
        WriteableBitmap newBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(scrBitmap.PixelWidth, scrBitmap.PixelHeight);
        for (int i = 0; i < scrBitmap.PixelWidth; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < scrBitmap.PixelHeight; j++)
            {
                //get the pixel from the scrBitmap image
                actulaColor = scrBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                // > 150 because.. Images edges can be of low pixel colr. if we set all pixel color to new then there will be no smoothness left.
                if (actulaColor.A > 150)
                    newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, actulaColor);
                else
                    newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
            }
        }
        return newBitmap;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether this is a good approach or not but I am getting a Null image with my code.

Can anyone suggest a easy way that can meet my requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return image;` will return well before your images finish downloading.

Comment: @Chubosaurus Software so what you suggest ??I have use imageopened event also but same result.Please see below post and you have suggested the image opened event...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436303/change-pixel-null-reference-exception-when-image-is-not-stored-in-local-folder

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware What can be done to avoid null image.Please suggest. There is requirement that I will need to use ImageConveter.

Comment: Are there any genius people who can help me